# Access module.exports from external file

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, marionette

I would like to view the contacts of a function from an external file.

MarionetteJS app.js file:

```
module.exports = functionToAccess = (function(superClass) {
  extend(functionToAccess, superClass);

  function functionToAccess() {
    this.doSomething = bind(this.doSomething, this);
    return functionToAccess.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  functionToAccess.prototype.defaults = {
    someProperty: 'some value',
    anotherProperty: 'another value',
    canAccessThis: false,
    wouldIlikeTo: true
  };

  [...]

  return functionToAccess;

})(Wrapper);
```

In an external PHP file, I am trying to alert or console.log the contents of *anything* from the above file, but preferably the `functionToAccess` function.

External JS script inside PHP file:

```
// Using the RequireJS CDN here resolves 'require is undefined'
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.2.0/require.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

var testFileLoad = require(['path/to/app'], function() {

});

console.log(testFileLoad);
```

This returns a `localRequire` function. How can I instead return `functionToAccess`?

Comment: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a variable in the callback function, which is where you will have access to your `path/to/app` code.  Try something like this:

```
require(['path/to/app'], function(functionToAccess) {
    functionToAccess(); // is available here
});
```